# How can I prove the folloing statement?

Tags: exponential-function

Let $X_{1}, . . . , X_{n}$ i.i.d. random variables with $X_{1} ∼ \text{Exp}(λ)$ for $λ > 0$.
Show that $$\min_{1≤i≤n} X_{i} ∼ \text{Exp}(nλ)$$.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! ... The community prefers/expects a question to include something of what the asker knows about the problem. (*What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?* etc) This helps answerers tailor their responses to best serve you, without wasting time (theirs or yours) explaining things you already understand or using techniques beyond your skill level. (It also helps convince people that you aren't simply trying to get them to do your homework for you. An isolated problem statement with no evidence of personal effort makes a poor impression, attracting down- and close-votes.)

Comment: This question is a direct copy of an exercise prompt without any reflection whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:-

$P(\min(X_{i})\geq x)=P(X_{1}\geq x,X_{2}\geq x,....X_{n}\geq x)=\\ P(X_{1}\geq x)P(X_{2}\geq x)...P(X_{n}\geq x)=(P(X_{1}\geq x))^{n}=(1-(1-e^{-\lambda x}))^{n}=e^{-n\lambda x} $.

Now let $Y$ have $\text{Exp}(n\lambda)$ distribution. Then what is the expression for $P(Y\geq x)$?.

So what can you conclude from the fact that $P(Y\leq x) = 1- P(Y\geq x)$?
Then what can you say about the CDF of Y and how does it compare with the cdf of $\min(X_{i})$ that we derived above?

Comment: I thought about your hints and about your questions and I came to an conclusion but I am not sure if it is correct:  P(Y≥x)= (P(Y≥x))^n = (1-(1-e^−nλx))^n=nλ e^−nλx

Comment: Dude...I practically wrote the entire solution for you. you have $P(\min(X_{i})\geq x)= e^{-n\lambda x}\implies\,P(\min(X_{i})\leq x) = 1-e^{-n\lambda x}=F(x)$ where $F$ is the cdf of a exponential $n\lambda$ variate. So the random variable $\min(X_{i})$ shares the same cdf of a exponential $n\lambda$ variate. Hence $\min(X_{i})\sim\exp(n\lambda)$.

Comment: If you are unwilling to show any work of your own I'll just delete my answer and vote to close your question. Not only are you violating the community guidelines , you are also not even trying to use mathjax.